# How to get the table results(multiple rows) from tlogrow in tsendmail component talend

Tags: java, email, talend

i have a db query and i would want to return the results in tabular format (one row after another )multiple rows in a tsendmail component and display in the email:

i tried using tbufferouput/input,but it only returns the last record since tjavarow ovewrites on each latest run with the new value  but i would want to get all the results at once in a single email ,in this case 9 rows at once
[image]

Comment: You could attach a file to the email, and put the result of the query in the file rather than in the body of the email.

Comment: yes i thought of that option,but its just that the requirement is to display the db results from the query in the table format as the message content in the email itself.Is there anyway to pull all the records and display them in the body of the email,coz if i use tjavarow its fetching only the latest record not the cumulative set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tJavaRow before your tSendMail to cumulate results into a single variable.

```
context.cumulateResult=context.cumulateResult+input_row.row1+" "+input_row.row2 etc
```

Then in tSendMail you can just set the content as context.cumulateResult (you can also use a global Variable instead of context variable).

Comment: yes i did the same thing in the javarow which goes like this:

 context.Step="NAME "+"\t"+"FILE_NAME "+"\t\t\t\t\t\t"+  "FILE_DATE "  +"\t\t\t"+"SIZE";

context.Step= context.Step+"\n "+input_row.NAME+"\t"+input_row.FILE_NAME +"\t"+input_row.FILE_DATE+"\t\t"+input_row.SIZE;

But it fetches only the last row from the resultset of the query in my email not the entire resultset.Not sure what else needs to be done

Comment: -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 NAME FILE_NAME       FILE_DATE    SIZE
 FAIL a.xls                                                        2020-10-29 10:42:17 100 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
i cant see the other records at all,since tjavarow fetches overwrites and captures only the last row from the db query

Comment: context.Step="NAME "+"\t"+"FILE_NAME "+"\t\t\t\t\t\t"+ "FILE_DATE " +"\t\t\t"+"SIZE";  => this will cause a problem because this will overwrite context.Step every time. With my solution you will concatenate lines instead of overwriting them. Read carefully this is not the same solution : you are concatenating your lines but you are overwriting with every incoming row.

Comment: makes sense now and its contcatenating as desired,thanks a lot